# difference in Datetime object result

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have 2 servers, both with PHP 5.5.
On server A, a simple echo of "new Datetime()" returns :

```
object(DateTime)#366 (3) { 
["date"]=> string(26) "2015-02-11 16:53:57.000000" 
["timezone_type"]=> int(3) 
["timezone"]=> string(3) "UTC" 
}
```

On server B however this returns :

```
object(DateTime)#366 (3) { 
["date"]=> string(19) "2015-02-11 16:53:57" 
["timezone_type"]=> int(3) 
["timezone"]=> string(3) "UTC" 
}
```

Notice how on server A the date includes the microseconds and and on server B there are no microseconds displayed.

Been looking crazy to find the cause of this but no luck. I want them both to exclude the microseconds. There must be some sort of global setting somewhere... I want to avoid explicitly setting the dateformat.
If anyone can direct me in the right direction that would be great !

Comment: Are you using a framework like Zend-Framework? ZF2 has its own DateTime object. Just noticed it is deprecated from v2.1.4.

Comment: I am using Laravel framework, both 4.1

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what caused that problem,
but you can get time in microseconds using following command:

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s'.substr((string)microtime(), 1, 8));
```